# How to write cookies using C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, setcookie, httpcookie

I have string in a text file and I want to save it as a cookie. However, my code is throwing a `System.NullReferenceException`. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```cs
public static bool SetCookie(string cookiename, string cookievalue, int iDaysToExpire)
{
    try
    {
         HttpCookie objCookie = new HttpCookie(cookiename);
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(objCookie);
         objCookie.Values.Add(cookiename, cookievalue);
         DateTime dtExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(iDaysToExpire);
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookiename].Expires = dtExpiry;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Which line does the exception happen on?

Comment: If there isn't a current web request, HttpContext.Current will be null.

Comment: ASP.Net or Console? Side note: it would make more sense to configure cookie first and than add it to the collection.

Comment: Hi, yes it is the HttpContext.Current is null. Is there any way I can do to avoid this? How to configure cookie and add to the collection? Can you explain more on it. Thank you.